# How to get MIME Content from Item Attachment with Microsoft Graph?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get the Mime Content from an item attachment.

Here is how I am getting the attachment currently:

```
var result = await _appClient
.Users[userId].Messages[messageId].Attachments[attachmentId].GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "microsoft.graph.itemattachment/item"};
});
```

Here is what is being returned:

```
{
"item": {
"categories": null,
"changeKey": null,
"createdDateTime": "2023-06-09T15:18:15+00:00",
"lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-06-09T15:18:15+00:00",
"additionalData": {},
"backingStore": {
"initializationCompleted": true,
"returnOnlyChangedValues": false
},
"id": "",
"odataType": "#microsoft.graph.message"
},
"contentType": null,
"isInline": false,
"lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-06-09T15:18:15+00:00",
"name": "RE: TONIGHT:   - 6:45 pm",
"size": 1533543,
"additionalData": {
"@odata.context": "\<link\>/$entity",
"item@odata.associationLink": "\<link\>",
"item@odata.navigationLink": "\<link\>"
},
"backingStore": {
"initializationCompleted": true,
"returnOnlyChangedValues": false
},
"id": "\<id\>",
"odataType": "#microsoft.graph.itemAttachment"
}
```

As I understand it, adding $value to the end of the url will give me what I am looking for. However, I am not aware of a way to do this using the Graph Library in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDK v5 doesn't support reading MIME content of message's attachment.

You need to create the request for the endpoint `/users/{user_id}/messages/{message_id}/attachments/{attachment_id}/$value` manually.

Create a request information for the endpoint `/users/{user_id}/messages/{message_id}/attachments/{attachment_id}`.

In next step, modify `UrlTemplate` of `RequestInformation` by replacing substring `{?%24select,%24expand}` with `/$value`.

At the end, execute the HTTP request specified by the given `RequestInformation` and tell graph client to deserialize the response as stream.

```
var requestInfo = await _appClient.Users[userId]
                          .Messages[messageId]
                          .Attachments[attachmentId]
                          .ToGetRequestInformation();

requestInfo.UrlTemplate = requestInfo.UrlTemplate.Replace("{?%24select,%24expand}", "/$value");

var content = await _appClient.RequestAdapter.SendPrimitiveAsync<Stream>(requestInfo);
```